# Browser auto refresh when i'm using setState (Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, codesandbox

could anyone show me the reason that the page auto refresh when i'm using setTodoItems in this link. I can't display the item which i were added before on my Todo table.

Here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todolist-tp8xk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Form` and it's getting submitted...

Change

```
<Form>
```

to

```
<Form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
```

Comment: Yup thats working, but can you explain how codesandbox work? i understand that e.preventDefault() that stop the page auto redirect to the end point but how its work in this situation?? Very appreciate if you do that.

Comment: By default when a form submits it sends the data to whatever page you are on (or whatever the forms target is).  This causes the page to reload.  You're just telling the form not to do that, it has nothing to do with code sandbox

Comment: And That's why my page auto reload, sorry for my dump question, i must be careful when i'm learning HTML5, thank you very much!